# Unable to ping server while connected via VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I am trying to understand more from the issues I frequently encounter with our network services.

I have a laptop, which has internet through my ISP router. When I try to connect to my work via VPN I often am not able to open any network shares or any other resource on the work network. I am trying to learn WHY.

When I run ip config I see both my LAN IP address as my VPN connection:

```
Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:a456:26ec:1:c15f:43b4:d1b:330a
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:a456:26ec:1:29e4:bbac:fc2d:704f
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c15f:43b4:d1b:330a%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.19
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::7e39:53ff:fec1:1b36%20
                                       192.168.1.1

PPP adapter VPN IAI Industrial Systems:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : iai.nl
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.5
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

My ARP tables:

```
C:\Users\bp>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.19 --- 0x14
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           7c-39-53-c1-1b-36     dynamic
  192.168.1.10          00-01-2e-3a-f7-e9     dynamic
  192.168.1.11          b8-27-eb-ef-ce-8f     dynamic
  192.168.1.13          00-11-32-4b-db-cf     dynamic
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  230.230.230.230       01-00-5e-66-e6-e6     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

Interface: 192.168.3.5 --- 0x2a
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.0.0                                 static
  192.168.1.10                                static
  192.168.1.11                                static
  192.168.1.20                                static
  192.168.3.10                                static
  224.0.0.2                                   static
  224.0.0.22                                  static
  255.255.255.255                             static
```

Routing table:

```
C:\Users\bp>route print
=========================================================================== Interface List
  5...30 e1 71 e7 f0 7a ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
 42...........................VPN IAI Industrial Systems
 12...b8 8a 60 a6 01 d1 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 16...00 ff e5 77 bb af ......TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
 20...b8 8a 60 a6 01 d0 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
 11...b8 8a 60 a6 01 d4 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
=========================================================================== Active Routes: Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway     Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.19     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    159.100.65.42  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.19     36
      192.168.0.0    255.255.248.0         On-link       192.168.3.5     26
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.19    291
     192.168.1.19  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.19    291
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.19    291
      192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.3.10      192.168.3.5     26
      192.168.3.5  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.3.5    281
    192.168.7.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.3.5    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.19    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.3.5    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.19    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.3.5    281
=========================================================================== Persistent Routes:   None

IPv6 Route Table
=========================================================================== Active Routes:  If Metric Network Destination      Gateway  20    291 ::/0                     fe80::7e39:53ff:fec1:1b36   1    331 ::1/128  On-link  13    331 2001::/32                On-link  13    331 2001:0:9d38:90d7:466:fbf0:b25c:e5d1/128
                                    On-link  20    291 2a02:a456:26ec:1::/64    On-link  20    291 2a02:a456:26ec:1:29e4:bbac:fc2d:704f/128
                                    On-link  20    291 2a02:a456:26ec:1:c15f:43b4:d1b:330a/128
                                    On-link  20    291 fe80::/64                On-link  13    331 fe80::/64                On-link  13    331 fe80::466:fbf0:b25c:e5d1/128
                                    On-link  20    291 fe80::c15f:43b4:d1b:330a/128
                                    On-link   1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link  20    291 ff00::/8                 On-link  13    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
=========================================================================== Persistent Routes:   None
```

When I try to ping a server at work which normally would reply I get:

```
C:\Users\bp>ping iai.nl

Pinging iai.nl [192.168.0.0] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

1) Is it normal to NOT have a default gateway on my VPN adapter, because its purpose is to route WITHIN the VPNs subnet (and for external IP addresses it would use my wifi network adapter?

2) For some weird reason "something" on my laptop thinks that iai.nl should respond on 192.168.0.0, which is not the case. Is this coming from the ARP table? If not, who/what is trying to ping 192.168.0.0?

Comment: *Request timed out* means your station thinks that it knows how to send the packets to the destination and sends them, but no answers obtained. But it can be wrong opinion. To understand you MUST show the routing table (`route print` output). PS. `192.168.0.0` address you try to ping is a network address, not a host address. Nobody will answer... *Is it normal to NOT have a default gateway on my VPN adapter* Yes. *"something" on my laptop thinks that iai.nl should respond on 192.168.0.0, which is not the case.* Chech `hosts` and `lmhosts` files content.

Comment: @Akina thanks, I added routing table too.PS: hosts file has no additional entries

Comment: Your local network (192.168.1.0/24) interfere with the network announced by VPN (192.168.0.0/21). That is bad - you cannot communicate with VPN net hosts having addresses 192.168.0.0...255.

Comment: About wrong translation `iai.nl` to `192.168.0.0`... This name is the name of domain accessible via VPN? and URL of some host at the same time? maybe simply add the correct mapping to `hosts` file?

Comment: @Akina thanks again for commenting. Is the VPN announced network 192.168.0.0/21? The IP adres on the virtual VPN adapter is 192.168.3.5 according to ipconfig. Nor do I understand why that would be an issue. Why would 192.168.1.* conflict with 192.168.0.* ?

Comment: *Is the VPN announced network 192.168.0.0/21?* Route to this subnet is available over VPN's 192.168.3.5 gateway (see routes table). What service except VPN may set this route? *The IP adres on the virtual VPN adapter is 192.168.3.5 according to ipconfig.* 192.168.3.5 is one of the addresses from 192.168.0.0/21 subnet.

Comment: *Why would 192.168.1.\* conflict with 192.168.0.\* ?* Not confilict. Intersect. Address range of the first subnet (192.168.1.0 -192.168.1.255) is a part of address range of the second one (192.168.0.0-192.168.7.255). So may exist 2 hosts with the same address (192.168.1.127 for example) - one host per each network. Only one of them is accessable - which is accessed through the route into the smallest subnet (192.168.1.0/24 in this case). Another host with the same address, which is located in the 192.168.0.0/21 subnet, is not accessible.

Comment: @Akina I still don't understand where you get this 192.168.0.0/*21* from?

Comment: From the routing table you show. Do you see the line `192.168.0.0    255.255.248.0         On-link       192.168.3.5     26`? That's it.

Comment: @Akina right! that's helpfull too! Thanks, already learned a lot from you !